# PowerShell command to trigger Jenkins job throws Authentication error

Tags: powershell, jenkins

```
$Auth = "admin:password"
$JenkinsURL = "http://$Auth@172.24.235.27:8080/"
$JobName = "TestItem1"
$JobToken = "token"
$FullURL = "$JenkinsURL/job/$JobName/build?token=$JobToken"
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing $FullURL
```

Above is the PowerShell code used for triggering Jenkins job. But while executing this I am facing "Authentication required" error. But the same command from `curl` is working fine.

I am not sure whether I am missing something in URL or missing some Jenkins plugin to provide access from PowerShell.

Comment: I don't know if that is the problem, but in `$FullURL` you will have **two** backslashes because you end the `$JenkinsURL` variable with a backslash too..

Comment: You may want to change the password of your Jenkins admin account as well as the token for the job. ***NOW!***

Comment: It's a private address...

Comment: @JacobColvin Yes. So?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But I don't think the issue is with admin password or job token, because the same url is working fine from gitbash command. Also the backslash is also not a problem.

Comment: @JacobColvin Yes. But I am accessing the URL from the same network. So hopefully it wont be the issue aswell.

Comment: @LeoDanny I was more replying to Ansgar, since it's a private address it's not like anyone can steal your keys and just login.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting an authentication error is that you will need to convert the authentication to base 64 string. Below is the script that you can use if you have not enabled the [CSRF](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/CSRF+Protection) in Jenkins.

```
$UserName = "admin"
$Password = "password"
$API_URL = "jenkinsservername"
$JobName = "TestItem1"
$JobToken = "token"
$header = @{}
$Params = @{}
$header.Add('Authorization', 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("$(${UserName}):$(${Password})")))
$Params['uri'] = "http://jenkinsservername/$JobName/build?token=$JobToken"
$Params['Method'] = 'Post'
$Params['Headers'] = $header
Invoke-RestMethod @Params
```

But If you have [CSRF](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/CSRF+Protection) Enabled in Jenkins then use below script

```
$UserName = "admin"
$Password = "password"
$API_URL = "jenkinsservername"
$JobName = "TestItem1"
$JobToken = "token"
$header = @{}
$header.Add('Authorization', 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("$(${UserName}):$(${Password})")))
$Params = @{uri = "http://${API_URL}:${API_Port}/crumbIssuer/api/json";
        Method = 'Get';
        Headers = $header;}
$API_Crumb = Invoke-RestMethod @Params
write-host $API_Crumb
$h.Add('Jenkins-Crumb', $API_Crumb.crumb)
$Params['uri'] = "http://jenkinsservername/$JobName/build?token=$JobToken"
$Params['Method'] = 'Post'
$Params['Headers'] = $header
Invoke-RestMethod @Params
```

Comment: Still I am facing some issue saying                                                                                                  Invoke-
WebRequest : HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /GitIntegration/build. Reason: Not Found
Powered by Jetty://
+ Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://$API_URL/$JobName/build?token=$JobToke ...
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: Can you post the uri that is created in $Params['uri'] = "http://jenkinsservername/$JobName/build?token=$JobToken"? From the error it seems like the  job URI is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, $h.Add... should be replaced with $header.Add, but all other look great

Comment: Don't think the problem is in auth data convertion to base64. I can trigger parametrized build by passing parameters hashtable with POST, but can't trigger 'Restart From Stage' win Invoke-Webrequest. I receive next error:
Invoke-RestMethod : 
window.location.replace('/securityRealm/commenceLogin?from=%2Fjob%2Ftestpass%2F');
Authentication required

However from bash curl 'Restart from stage' works well.

Answer (score 0):

@Mike correctly described the instructions for working with the jenkins api when using CSRF. But I would like to add that when creating crumbs, the session and cookies are also taken into account.

The code that works for me is as follows:

```
$UserName = "admin"
$Password = "password"
$API_URL = "jenkinsservername"
$JobName = "TestItem1"
$JobToken = "token"
$header = @{}
$header.Add('Authorization', 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("$(${UserName}):$(${Password})")))
$Params1 = @{uri = "http://${API_URL}:${API_Port}/crumbIssuer/api/json";
            Method = 'Get';
            SessionVariable = 'Session';
            Headers = $header;}
$API_Crumb = Invoke-RestMethod @Params1
write-host $API_Crumb
$header.Add('Jenkins-Crumb', $API_Crumb.crumb)
$Params2 = @{}
$Params2['uri'] = "http://jenkinsservername/$JobName/build?token=$JobToken"
$Params2['Method'] = 'Post'
$Params2['Headers'] = $header
Invoke-RestMethod @Params2 -WebSession $Session
```

Also consider if the job is in a folder, then the uri will be different.
For example, if MyJob is in MyFolder then the uri will be:

```
http://jenkinsservername/job/MyFolder/job/MyJob/build?token=JobToken
```

You can see this path in the place where you assigned the token for the job